# Checksum error while installing OpenCV via HomeBrew

Tags: opencv, homebrew, gnutls, homebrew-cask

I am trying to install OpenCV, one of it's dependencies failed to installed with the following error.

```
==> Downloading https://gitlab.com/gnutls/gnutls/commit/ef80617d1e17e0878a909baad62a75ba265c0e00.patch
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  ChecksumMismatchError: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: 3b1634fa348c0f0064e43f3fb673e30a5e46f2b51cd6cd0d4a0cbf326e71c90e
  Actual: 34480b13120e2167060795060b6738c26622c341498cf6303b17b143642b14cd
 Archive: /Users/AX/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/0c113ab0098bc4c3f2e8f410741b6104f2928fe63eb38cf98f8dcc3362f02ac4--ef80617d1e17e0878a909baad62a75ba265c0e00.patch
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

I even removed the file, as suggested but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I sorted it out after google. Perform the following steps:

- `brew edit gnutls`
- scroll down to the lines with:
  sha256 `3b1634fa348c0f0064e43f3fb673e30a5e46f2b51cd6cd0d4a0cbf326e71c90e`

  - Replace with sha256 `34480b13120e2167060795060b6738c26622c341498cf6303b17b143642b14cd`
  - Run again.